# Evaluating Sums Combinatorially

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Consider the following finite sums:

(1) $\sum k(k!)$ for k from 1 to n

(2) $\sum (k-1)(n-k)$ from 1 to n

I am trying to determine how to evaluate these sums combinatorially.  It seems the first is describing the number of ways to arrange k objects k times for each k and the second is describing the number of ways to count the number of ways to choose from two piles of labelled objects with replacement.  Are these ideas in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, we have $n+1$ people,  named $0,1, 2,\dots, n$, and lined up in a row from left to right, in that order.

We want to rearrange them, so that at least one person moves.   There are clearly $(n+1)!-1$ ways to do this. Let us count the number of rearrangements another way.

For any $k$, with $1\le k\le n$, let $N_k$ be the number of rearrangements in which the *rightmost person* who moves is $k$.

*Where* $k$ moves to can be any of the $k$ places $0$ to $k-1$.  Once we have chosen this place,  there are $k!$ rearrangements of the remaining people $0$ to $k-1$ into the positions $0$ to $k$. Thus $N_l=k\cdot k!$, and the number of rearrangements in which at least one person moves is $\sum_1^n k\cdot k!$.

For the second problem, one way to visualize is that we have $n$ people lined up in a row, and we want to choose $3$ of them. There are $\binom{n}{3}$ ways to do this.

To count another way, suppose the "middle" person chosen is $k$, where $k$ goes from $2$ to $n-1$. For any such $k$, the person in front of her can be chosen in $k-1$ ways, and then the person behind her can be chosen in $n-k$ ways. Adding up over all $k$ gives us the total number of of ways to choose $3$ people.

Comment: Very nice explanation!  However, doesn't it suggest that the number of ways to move when the largest number that moves is k for k=1 should be 1(0!) since there is no way for the number of remaining numbers to be chosen?  Granted, this is just the same as 1! but I can't help but think little things like this throw me off when coming up with explanations.

Comment: The names were chosen from $0$ so this part would go smoothly. There is undoubtedly a slightly better "story" to go with the idea.

Comment: @user73041: I have written down a combinatorial interpretation of the second sum. Again, the "story" could be refined. Funnier is always better, then people remember it.

Comment: I've looked through some of your other responses and that seems to be what I've found.  The 'Lefty' story was particularly memorable for some reason.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: To be sure, is the person behind chosen in $n-k$ ways because of cancellation occuring from your choice of range for k (i.e. k between 2 and n-1)?

Comment: The restrictions are just so that there will be at least one in front and behind. We can remove the restriction, that would just add a couple of terms equal to $0$.

Comment: Great, I see what you mean thank you.